Leveraging HDFS as GeoServer storage
I'd like to build a link between GeoServer and HDFS to improve the storage capacity of my GeoServer instance to avoid saturating the storage of the machine in which GeoServer runs.
The objective of my project is that of building a Dataplatform in which one of the functionality is leverage GeoServer to work with satellite images.
Given the volume of such images my local server memory would saturate rapidly. The idea is to connect GeoServer with an existing HDFS high-availability cluster. I've done various searches on web but I've found very few ideas of how do that.
So I want ask you if someone had already do something similar.
At the moment the promising idea that I tried to develop is that of using the geoserver plugin "ImageI/O-Ext GDAL Coverage Extension" and "VSI Virtual File System Support" that could leverage the ability of GDAL in using virtual file system vsihdfs as the bridge that connects with hdfs.
After configuring all of this, not without any effort, this idea started to look promising but some issues still persist: I am still not able to connect to HDFS from Geoserver; however, if I try to access HDFS via plain GDAL library (e.g. gdalinfo /vsihdfs//{HDFS_PATH_TO_FILE}, gdalinfo /vsihdfs/hdfs://{fs.defaultFS}/{HDFS_PATH_TO_FILE}, gdalinfo /vsihdfs/hdfs:///{HDFS_PATH_TO_FILE} ) I'm able to succesfully retrieve data from HDFS.
In details, when leveraging VSI with Geoserver the problem seems that when I give the path of my file on HDFS in the format that the libraries suggest (e.g /vsihdfs/hdfs://localhost:9000/my.tif) there internals pattern matching seems to not support the ":" character throwing the following exception:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: could not parse invalid VSI location: /vsihdfs/hdfs://myhacluster/abds/datalake/harbour/tif_geoserver/20190802/NDVI/20190802_NDVI_TPQ.tif
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not parse invalid VSI location: /vsihdfs/hdfs://myhacluster/abds/datalake/harbour/tif_geoserver/20190802/NDVI/20190802_NDVI_TPQ.tif
    at org.geotools.vsi.VSIDataset.<init>(VSIDataset.java:44)
    at org.geotools.vsi.VSIDataset.fromObject(VSIDataset.java:61)
    at org.geotools.vsi.VSIReader.<init>(VSIReader.java:54)
    at org.geotools.vsi.VSIFormat.getReader(VSIFormat.java:49)
    at org.geotools.vsi.VSIFormat.getReader(VSIFormat.java:27)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getGridCoverageReader(ResourcePool.java:1696)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getGridCoverageReader(ResourcePool.java:1636)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CoverageStoreInfoImpl.getGridCoverageReader(CoverageStoreInfoImpl.java:57)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor354.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.ModificationProxy.invoke(ModificationProxy.java:155)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy55.getGridCoverageReader(Unknown Source)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPageProvider.getItemsInternal(NewLayerPageProvider.java:98)
    ... 142 more

So I then tried /vsihdfs//abds/datalake/harbour/tif_geoserver/20190802/NDVI/20190802_NDVI_TPQ.tif assuming that GDAL recognize the default HDFS location (from $HADOOP_CONF_DIR configuration files), but again the pattern matching still fails because of two "/" without any character between. Both paths are running regularly with GDAL plain utilities programs as gdalinfo (as examples above).
To avoid this issue I finally saw that the plugin VSI leverages on VRT file format of GDAL so I tried to exclude it using directly VRT stores, but in that case building a .vrt files with gdalbuilvrt and trying to using it as Geoserver store the following error appear:
ERROR 4: `/vsihdfs//path/to/my/tif' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.

Is this the correct way to bridge GeoServer with an HDFS storage?
